# condition for value not in array or value different from all elements in array

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I would like to find a condition in jquery to be sure that the `id` of the data found by `.grep` is different from all the values from a vector, with something like this :

```
var matchedAgainstBrand = $.grep(prodata, function(v,i) {
    return v['id'] !== matchedProIds ;
});
```

or this

```
var matchedAgainstBrand = $.grep(prodata, function(v,i) {
    return $.inArray( v['id'], matchedProIds ) == -1;
});
```

(but these two do not work !)

where `matchedProIds` is a vector of integers, defined like this :

```
var matchedProIds = [];
for (i=0; i< matchedPro.length; i++) {
     matchedProIds.push(matchedPro[i]['id']);
}
```

Can you help with a condition that (un)match a value against a vector ?

Comment: You want us to write it for you?

Comment: @JonathanM mmmhh yes !?

Comment: [Array.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the suggestion from @Matt Burland :

```
var matchedAgainstBrand = $.grep(prodata, function(v,i) {
    return matchedProIds.indexOf(v['id']) == -1;
});
```